# Y axis sets on zero after changing the data, on the graph, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, plotly, grafana

I am using variables, dynamic text and plotly with javascript in grafana.

At the first load the graph shows complete

[image]

After changing the data, its like the hole Y axis sets on zero maximun and minimun.

[image]

After realoading the page it displays the graph with out issues

[image]

The Y axis will change from size, on the layout configuration I set

layout:{

....

autorange: true,

....
}

Any suggestion thay may help, thanks in advance.